# How to update selected tables in a Postgres database schema from a database dump on another server?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have a database and some tables are updated periodically on the dev server and need to be pushed to the database on the prod server.  What's the appropriate way to migrate the updated tables from the dev database to the prod database with pg_dump and pg_restore? I could dump the whole database on the dev server and restore it on the prod server, but some tables contain dynamic data (created/updated by applications) that are different between the two databases, so these tables on the prod server must be preserved. Still some tables contain static data that won't be changed and need not be updated on the prod server though it's okay to update them.

So basically what I want to do is to update the data in some tables of the database on the prod server with the data of the corresponding tables from the database on the dev server, using pg_dump and pg_restore (version 15.4). Thanks.

P.S.  I've read the manual pages of pg_dump and pg_restore, but still don't have a clear idea how to do what I want. I had tried a few tests and didn't work as I expected.  I also searched online and didn't see posts addressing the same issue.

Comment: Why when there is [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html). Just set up the link and query directly from the dev server to the prod server.

Comment: This is going to be a manual process (read: doing it one table at a time), unless you have done some preparation in advance - specifically you need to ensure you keep the schemas of both databases in sync and then have some mechanism to identify records that need to be copied for example: if every table has an `updated_at` column and you can simply copy all records after a certain timestamp. If you have done the prep you can either write your own script to do it or find a third party tool that can "replicate data" based on a timestamp.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks.  It's not desirable for the prod server to directly query the database on the dev server because anything could happen to the database on the dev server (tables could be dropped, data could be deleted or messed up, etc. ).  But I haven't looked at postgres_fdw in details yet and don't know if postgres_fdw set up to sync specified tables on the prod server with the corresponding tables on the dev server.

Comment: @DavidT the schemas of both databases are the same, but data would be different.  There's no need to get to the record/row levels, only need to replace the data of the entire tables in question while leaving other tables alone.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `--clean --if-exists` offers the full table overwrite, while using `--schema='specific_schema'` and `--table='specific_table'` you can narrow down what's [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html#PG-DUMP-OPTIONS) supposed to target, skipping all else.

```bash
pg_dump -d your_dev_db -U your_dev_user -p 5432 \
   --table='your_schema.your_table' --clean --if-exists \
| psql -d your_prod_db -U your_prod_user -p 5432 --ON_ERROR_STOP
```

[`postgres_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77640927/how-to-update-selected-tables-in-a-postgres-database-schema-from-a-database-dump#comment136877928_77640927) by [@Adrian Klaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver) can let you link objects on `dev` to be visible and accessible on `prod` as if they were present locally, which lets you either just use them directly, or reference them from DML to perform the necessary `prod` updates based on `dev` on the spot, from within `prod`. [Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/O--ZJBvW)

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS dev_public_schema;

CREATE SERVER foreign_server
        FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
        OPTIONS (dbname 'dev');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR current_user
        SERVER foreign_server
        OPTIONS (user 'postgres');
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public
   FROM SERVER foreign_server 
   INTO dev_public_schema;

INSERT INTO public.my_prod_table1 
SELECT * FROM dev_public_schema.my_dev_table1
WHERE created_at>='yesterday'::timestamptz;
```

The doc also documents multiple [replication methods](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/different-replication-solutions.html#DIFFERENT-REPLICATION-SOLUTIONS) that let you set up an automatic process of moving the data from `dev` to `prod`. In particular, you can set up [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html) to "replay" on `prod` [specific](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication-row-filter.html#LOGICAL-REPLICATION-ROW-FILTER-RULES) changes that took place on `dev`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The problem with --table switch for pg_restore (according to the man page) is that it doesn't cover subsidiary objects such as indexes and other database objects the specified tables may depend on.  Also you can't include a schema name with the table to specify a table in a specific schema.  I'll explore postgres_fdw to see if it can be set up to sync specified tables.

Comment: My recommendation is not `pg_restore` with `--table` - that switch is somewhat different from `pg_dump`'s. The latter **does** include relevant indexes, sequences and constraints. It also **does** let you grab a schema-qualified table. You can pipe `pg_dump` straight to `psql`, you don't necessarily need `pg_restore` at all but regardless of which one you pick, neither will attempt to restore anything `pg_dump` doesn't give them, in any way that wasn't specified by `pg_dump`, unless clearly instructed.

Comment: `pg_dump` will even rebuild referential integrity: if the table you transfer has a foreign key to a table you are *not* transferring, then after it's moved, it'll still get correctly linked to the corresponding table and column on the target database.